# Bind OCI sysdate() to PDO parameter?

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, oracle-call-interface

I want to bind sysdate function in my PDO prepared query :

```
$db = new PDO('oci:dbname=database;charset=UTF8', 'user', 'pass');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$query = $db->prepare('SELECT :func FROM DUAL');
$query->execute(array(':func' => 'SYSDATE()'));
var_dump($query->fetch());
```

The result return this :

```
array (size=2)
  ':FUNC' => string 'SYSDATE()' (length=9)
  0 => string 'SYSDATE()' (length=9)
```

I want to get the system date of my oracle database. Is it possible ?

Can you help me to make my trick ?

Comment: No, it isn't possible. Bind parameters are a tool to inject data (such as numbers or string literals) and make sure they don't become code. You're asking for the opposite. Why do you need to do it?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález OCI supports [`IN` and `OUT` binds](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php), but not via PDO as far as I know.

Comment: A reflection that arises now, seeing the flood of downvotes: is code in question a simplified test case to illustrate the issue or you really only want to run a plain static `SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL` query?

Comment: @timclutton I've never used PDO for Oracle (only OCI8) but he doesn't seem to want OUT binds (and IN binds are clearly working for him since he gets `SELECT 'SYSDATE()' FROM DUAL`).

Comment: Good point(s); I took the question at face value. Either way (your answer or mine) the problem should be solved. Perhaps OP can comment.

Answer (score -1):

Bind parameters are a tool to inject data (such as numbers or string literals) and make sure they don't become code. However, you are asking for the exact opposite: you want data to become code. So I'm afraid you simply cannot use that technique.

You'll have to compose SQL dynamically using good old PHP string manipulation functions, e.g.:

```
$sql = sprintf('SELECT %s AS "result" FROM DUAL', 'SYSDATE');
```

Needless to say, you should never allow free input for obvious security reasons. If you want to switch functions you'd better follow a white list approach, e.g.:

```
switch (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'option')) {
    case 'time':
        $function = 'SYSDATE';
        break;
    // ... more case statements
    default:
        $function = null;
}
if (!is_null($function)) {
    $sql = sprintf('SELECT %s AS result FROM DUAL', $function);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Oracle (via the [OCI module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php) in PHP) *does* support both [`IN` and `OUT` binds](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php). They are provided for running `PL/SQL` and returning the result. In your case, running a plain `SQL` `SELECT` statement, you don't need to do that.

And note that `SYSDATE` is not a function so you mustn't use parentheses.

Here's a working example using `PDO`:

```
$db = new PDO('oci:dbname=database;charset=UTF8', 'user', 'pass');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$query = $db->prepare('SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL');
$query->execute();
var_dump($query->fetch());
```

Comment: Actually i have this code but I wanted a tool function for debug.