# How do I pass a sysdate in an oci_bind_by_name function to update a record?

Tags: php, oracle, date

How do I pass a sysdate to date column in an oracle table using oci_bind_by_name function

For example

```
$upquery = "UPDATE mytable SET fieldA = :b_ssn, fieldUpdated = :b_updateDate where fieldKey = :b_key";
$whatsup = oci_parse($conn, $upquery);
oci_bind_by_name($whatsup, ':b_ssn', $the_ssn, -1, OCI_B_INT);

oci_bind_by_name($whatsup, ':b_updateDate, sysdate, ... ? // <--

oci_bind_by_name($whatsup, ':b_key', $the_key, -1, OCI_B_INT);
oci_execute($whatsup);
```

How do i pass it?

---

ignore this... why not use sysdate in the query LOL

Comment: You cannot pass identifiers as parameters, only literals. In other words, you can pass your custom variables but no tables, columns, functions, pseudo-rows... This is not specific to PHP or Oracle, it's how all prepared statements implementations I'm aware of work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993377/bind-oci-sysdate-to-pdo-parameter

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
$upquery = "UPDATE mytable SET fieldA = :b_ssn, fieldUpdated = SYSDATE where fieldKey = :b_key";
```

I am not familiar with php, perhaps this one works also:

```
oci_bind_by_name($whatsup, ':b_updateDate', new DateTime(), SQLT_ODT)
```